# Extending BindableBase to be UI thread safe for WinUI3/Uno Platform

Tags: c#, thread-safety, winui-3, uno-platform

I'm currently using the `BindableBase` implementation from the [quiz game example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-appsample-networkhelper/blob/master/DemoApps/QuizGame/Common/BindableBase.cs) recommended in the "Databinding in depth" MSDN article. Since I needed to be able to update the properties from a background thread, and didn't feel like wrapping all writes in `DispatcherQueue_TryEnqueue`, I modified `BindableBase` like this:

```
public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //cache the synchronization context on object creation, once
    private static SynchronizationContext _SynchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    /* ...unchanged code from original version... */
    
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        //notify all delegates on the UI thread's synchronization context
        _SynchronizationContext.Post(d => {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }, null);
    }
}
```

This seems to work as intended, with the obvious caveat that all derived objects must be created on the UI thread, which is fine for me. However I'm no threading expert so I was wondering if this could cause problems in unexpected ways. I also wrote this before I discovered `DispatcherQueue`; should I be using that over synchronization context when invoking the `PropertyChanged` delegates?

**---Update---**

I should clarify why I'm trying to do this. By making the changes above I make the object in charge of making sure it's always invoking `PropertyChanged` delegates on the UI thread, instead of the consumer of the object. Now I can write code like this:

**Bindable Object**

```
public class BindableObject : BindableBase
{
    private int _SomeValue = 0;
    public int SomeValue
    {
        get => _SomeValue;
        set => SetProperty(ref _SomeValue, value);
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind MyObject.SomeValue, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

**MyPage.cs**

```
public sealed partial class MyPage : Page
{
    public BindableObject MyObject { get; init; } = new();
    
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
    {
        await Task.Run(async () => {
            //do something interesting here
            
            MyObject.SomeValue = 1;
                //no call to DispatcherQueue
                //but no exceptions and x:Bind updates correctly
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The motivation for this is because most writes to my business objects will be from a background thread, which is parsing data from a blocking pipe.

Comment: It's just more costly in terms of performance and threading context switches, but it's all relative (and it seems you don't have the choice anyway). Note you could add a check to determine if the thread is the UI one and don't switch if not needed. If this particular object is always accessed on different thread, I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I also wrote this before I discovered DispatcherQueue; should I be using that over synchronization context?

Yes, AFAIK, the `DispatcherQueue` is the way to go to access UI from a non-UI thread.

> This seems to work as intended, with the obvious caveat that all derived objects must be created on the UI thread, which is fine for me. However I'm no threading expert so I was wondering if this could cause problems in unexpected ways.

If possible, you should instantiate your object first, then only use the `DispatcherQueue` to access the UI.

This a sample code using the `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm`.

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using Microsoft.UI.Dispatching;
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ObservableCollections;

public record HeavyItem(TimeSpan TimeSpan);

public partial class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private readonly DispatcherQueue dispatcherQueue;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<HeavyItem> items = new();

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        this.dispatcherQueue = DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread();
    }

    [RelayCommand(IncludeCancelCommand = true)]
    private Task Test(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                while (true)
                {
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    // First, instantiate the item,
                    HeavyItem item = new(stopwatch.Elapsed);
                    // then use the DispatcherQueue to add the item.
                    this.dispatcherQueue?.TryEnqueue(() => Items.Add(item));

                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
            }
        }, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace ObservableCollections;

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainPageViewModel ViewModel { get; } = new();
}
```

**MainPage.xaml**

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="ObservableCollections.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:ObservableCollections"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
        <StackPanel
            Grid.Row="0"
            Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button
                Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.TestCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                Content="Start" />
            <Button
                Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.TestCancelCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                Content="Cancel" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ScrollViewer
            Grid.Row="1"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled">
            <ItemsRepeater ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: This is what I'm specifically trying to avoid, if at all possible. I've updated the question to include what my goal is. If you think that what I'm doing is a bad idea, could you please explain why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Can you be more specific about what you are trying to avoid?

Comment: The code that is problematic is `PropertyChanged?.Invoke` in the base class; if that isn't done on the UI thread then you get the non UI thread access exception. This is why `dispatcherQueue?.TryEnqueue` is needed here. But this needs to be done every time the background thread updates the object. By modifying the base class I am able to allow the background thread to update the object as usual, because `BindableBase` now invokes all delegates on the UI thread by default, using `_SynchronizationContext.Post`.

Comment: I guess I understand now what you are trying to do. You want to hide the explicit UI access rituals, right? I'm not sure if this is a bad idea or not. Just I've never tried/seen that way. I prefer the explicit way though.

Comment: BTW, there was an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2609) in the GitHub repo. Might help.